# How can I bold part of a string in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

If I create a label like this:

```
var label = UILabel(...)
label.text = first_name + ", " + age
self.view.addSubview(label)
```

How can I change the age of the label to bold, but keep the first_name normal weight?

Comment: You need to use NSAttributedString which is a special string that lets you makes pieces of it look different (i.e. bolding)...then set the label.attributedText instead

Answer (score 7):

You can use an attributed string. Here, the bold size is 15, but you can also change that point size if you want.

```
var age = "13"

var att = [NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(15)]

var boldAge = NSMutableAttributedString(string:age, attributes:att)

// Assigning to a UILabel
yourLabel.attributedText = boldAge
```

so now you would want to assign your text like this:

```
label.attributedText = first_name + ", " + boldAge
```

Comment: I think the code has been slightly changed. Here is the updated version:

```
 var normalText = "Normal Text "
 var boldText = " Bold Text"
 var attributedStringNormal = NSMutableAttributedString(string:normalText)

var attrs = [NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 15)]
var boldString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: boldText, attributes:attrs)
attributedStringNew.append(boldString)
```